# How to save time using java.sql.Date?

Tags: java

Currently in my code I am using following setter method to save current date and time to DB. But its saving only date, not time.

```
emp.setJoiningDate(new java.sql.Date(System.currentTimeMillis()))
```

**Method Declaration :**

```
setJoiningDate(java.sql.Date joiningDate) {
this.joiningDate= joiningDate;
}
```

**I dont want to change parameter type (java.sql.Date).** Please help

Comment: A java.sql.Date represents a date, without time. So this type is completely inappropriate for what you want to do.

Comment: java.sql.date doesn't store time. Are you looking to store both? Try `SimpleDateFormat`

Comment: "I don't want to change parameter type". Well, then you won't get what you want.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From oracle documentation on java.sql.Date

> ...SQL Date values do not have a time component.

If you want time use java.sql.Timestamp

Comment: Got it . Thanks Buddy